# C/XC8 Syntax: Can invert and AND operation be used in the same statement?

Tags: c, syntax, xc8

I am writing c code in xc8 compiler for PIC micro-controller. This code will control a fan's(motor) on/off and speed using CCP module.

To turn on/off the CCP module and consequently the fan, I am toggling the CCP1CON bits like so

```
ccp1conValue = CCP1CON;
ccp1conValue = ~ccp1conValue & 0x0F;
ccp1conValue = CCP1CON;
```

My concern is that is this syntax correct and acceptable in XC8? Can I use invert and AND operation in the same statement or I need to do them separately? Or is there a better way to do it altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's valid C syntax, and any slightly compliant compiler should handle it with grace. While people often push what is reasonable to do in a single line of C code, I would personally judge what you've done to be perfectly acceptable.

One thing to watch out for whenever you combine multiple operations is operator precedence.

Your statement:

```
~ccp1conValue & 0x0F
```

is equivalent to:

```
(~ccp1conValue) & 0x0F
```

This is likely what you were trying to do, but it's good to keep in mind.

Also, that last line:

```
ccp1conValue = CCP1CON;
```

should probably be:

```
CCP1CON = ccp1conValue;
```

instead.

Depending on if you need to keep the value, you may be able to replace those three lines with:

```
CCP1CON = ~CCP1CON & 0x0F;
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Yeah I totally missed the `CCP1CON = ccp1conValue;` Thanks for pointing that out. And do you suggest that I should always use parentheses for the likes of above case?

Comment: @Idrees For this particular case, I don't think the parentheses are needed. They add noise, and I think that the `~` being directly against the variable makes it clear that you know that its precedence is higher.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use invert and AND operation in the same statement or I need to do them separately?

You can absolutely use bitwise negation and bitwise AND in the same expression, as shown.

However, this is seems fishy for other reasons:

> I am toggling the CCP1CON bits like so
>
> ```
> ccp1conValue = CCP1CON;
> ccp1conValue = ~ccp1conValue & 0x0F;
> ccp1conValue = CCP1CON;
> ```

1. as @ThomasJager already observed, you appear to have reversed the operands of the last assignment statement.  As written, there is no effect on `CCP1CON`, and the result of the bitwise manipulations is not retained anywhere.  A clever compiler might even diagnose this for you.  If neither `ccp1conValue` nor `CCP1CON` is `volatile` then I would expect the compiler to optimize out the first two statements altogether.
2. Supposing that (1) were corrected by flip-flopping the operands, that series of statements would do more than just toggle some bits in `CCP1CON`.  It would toggle the lowest-order four bits, *and clear all the others*.

> Or is there a better way to do it altogether?

For one thing, it's not clear what good you think the temporary variable is doing for you.  Even if `CCP1CON` is `volatile`, the above code (after correction of the last statement) is equivalent to

```
CCP1CON = ~CCP1CON & 0x0F;
```

I find that clearer.

Moreover, **if your objective is to modify *only* the four least-significant bits**, or if the higher-order bits don't matter, then I would personally perform the flip via the bitwise exclusive OR operator instead of the bitwise negation operator:

```
CCP1CON = CCP1CON ^ 0x0F;
```

That's clearer still, at least to me, and if you need to avoid changing the more-significant bits then it does so, whereas your version does not.  I emphasize, however, that this is updating `CCP1CON` with a different value than the corrected version of the original code would.

**If the more-significant bits in fact don't matter** then you could also consider just a flat, unmasked inversion:

```
CCP1CON = ~CCP1CON;
```

The assigned value is different from both the other two alternatives, and this does not have the advantage of the XOR version of making it clear which bits you actually care about, but if it does the (a) right thing then it has the advantage of being about as simple as it can be.

Comment: Well, @Idrees, if you can rely on the top nybble starting out zero, then either of the first two alternatives will preserve that.  The question is whether you want to consider the possibility that the top nybble may sometimes start nonzero, and if so, then whether you want to preserve it or clear it (or something else).

Comment: This tip was very helpful 'cause I actually was not comfortable using negation tbh. I want to keep the higher nibble `zero` always so `XOR` would be my go to. The reason for using the variable is that I want to somehow detect whether the fan is `ON` or `OFF` and use that status to control the speed or not. Since `0x0F` is decimal `15` and `0x00` is decimal `0`, this value stored in `ccp1conValue` would serve as a "check" to know whether to control the speed or not.

Comment: This is updated version of the previous comment. It took me long to edit so I had to repost. Sorry for the inconvenience